# formatting data from a DateField using ModelForm - Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm creating an edit view that uses ModelForm, and I'd like the form's date field to appear in the following format: "**%d/%m/%Y**".

However, regardless of what I do, when the edit page is called, the date is displayed in the format "**%m-%d-%Y**".

*models.py*

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    data_nascimento = models.DateField()
    rg = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    responsavel = models.ForeignKey('Pessoa', related_name='dependentes', blank=True, null=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='pessoas')

    usuario_alteracao = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    data_alteracao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

*settings.py (DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS and DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)*

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

*pessoas_forms.py*

```
class PessoaForm(ModelForm):

    data_nascimento = DateField(
        input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
        widget=DateInput(attrs={'class': "input", 'placeholder': "Ex.: dd/mm/aaaa", "OnKeyPress":"mask('##/##/####', this)"}))

    class Meta:
        model = Pessoa
        fields = ['nome', 'sobrenome', 'cpf', 'data_nascimento', 'rg', 'foto']
        exclude = ['usuario', 'usuario_alteracao', 'data_criacao', 'data_alteracao', 'responsavel']
        widgets = {
            'nome': TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"}),
            'sobrenome': TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"}),
            'cpf': TextInput(attrs={'class': "input", 'placeholder': "Ex.: 000.000.000-00", "OnKeyPress":"mask('###.###.###-##', this)"}),
            'rg': TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"}),
        }
```

*views.py*

```
def get(self, request, id):

        try:
            pessoa = Pessoa.objects.get(id=id)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(request, 'Not Found.')
            return redirect('pessoas')

        pessoa_form = PessoaForm(instance=pessoa)

        context = {
            'pessoa_form': pessoa_form,
            'id': pessoa.id
        }

        return render(request, 'sagasystem/configuracoes/pessoas/editar_pessoa.html', context)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a DateInput widget for your date fields? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#timeinput

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. You can see in 'people_forms.py' above.

Comment: Your settings and form are looking good, the most probably is that you have some error in your template, if you can post it, maybe i can help debugging

Comment: You also probably need to set in your settings.py:

 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the widget how to display the date, using the [`format`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateInput.format) argument.

```
data_nascimento = DateField(
    widget=DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs={'class': "input", 'placeholder': "Ex.: dd/mm/aaaa", "OnKeyPress":"mask('##/##/####', this)"}))
```